# How to show these limits are zero?

Tags: calculus, limits

I want to prove the following limits, but I fail to do both of them. Does the answer depend on the base of logarithm?

1. $\lim \limits _{n \to \infty} \dfrac{n^k}{n^{\log n}} = 0$, where $k \in \Bbb R$.
2. $\lim \limits _{n \to \infty} \dfrac{a^n}{n^{\log n}} = 0$, where $a \in \Bbb R$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Take the $\log$ of the limits.

First question:

> Note that $\log\left(\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}\frac{n^k}{n^{\log n}}\right)=\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}\log\left(\frac{n^k}{n^{\log n}}\right)=\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}\left(k\log(n)-\log(n)\times\log(n)\right)\rightarrow-\infty$

Second question (it looks wrong unless $a\leq1$):

> Note that $\log\left(\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}\frac{a^n}{n^{\log n}}\right)=\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}\log\left(\frac{a^n}{n^{\log n}}\right)=\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}\left(n\log(a)-\log(n)\times\log(n)\right)\rightarrow-\infty$ only if $a\leq1$.

Comment: Does L hospital's rule work for this case?

Comment: I don't think it would help much: when you differentiate $n^{\log n}$ you create a more complicated expression.